# SMTP (port 587) does not work from localhost

Tags: iptables

If I to connect to the Mailserver (port 587) from external box, everything works. If I try it from the host running the VM, or from another VM on same host it does not work.

I found something like...

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:587
```

but that also does not work. What's with the SNAT, is this something my configuration is missing?

```
root@vm ~ # iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.2 on Sat Jan 16 05:49:53 2021
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [563710:254092285]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1055444:391947870]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 16 05:49:53 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.2 on Sat Jan 16 05:49:53 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [9275:477822]
:INPUT ACCEPT [627:46402]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2171:130644]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1384:80860]
-A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:80
-A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:443
-A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:25
-A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:465
-A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:587
-A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:993
-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 16 05:49:53 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.2 on Sat Jan 16 05:49:53 2021
*filter
:INPUT DROP [31177:1522159]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1056186:391997142]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i vmbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 655 -m set --match-set ip_block_vpn src -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 16 05:49:53 2021
```

Enabled

```
root@vm ~ # sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 1
root@vm ~ #
```

Connection attempt with Telnet

```
root@vm ~ # telnet 192.168.1.100 587
Trying 192.168.1.100...
Connected to 192.168.1.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@vm ~ # telnet 127.0.0.1 587
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@vm ~ #
```

Comment: better show a complete `iptables-save` output. Also, your rule is very unusual, it hardly could do anything. `-t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo` is a very strange combination. What did you planned to achieve with this?

Comment: Sending E-Mail from 192.168.1.111.

Comment: Guess the issue is, that the IP packet sent to mail.example.com resolves to the IP of the VM-Host, so it is routed to localhost and not going out the wire.

Comment: At least the ping from 192.168.1.111 to mail.example.com is 0.1 ms...


    root@debian:~# ping mail.example.com
    PING mail.example.com (000.000.000.000) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from mail.example.com (000.000.000.000): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
    64 bytes from mail.example.com (000.000.000.000): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.120 ms
    ^C
    --- mail.example.com ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.055/0.087/0.120/0.033 ms
    root@debian:~#

Comment: Please, show all network configuration, at least it should include a host, a VM, a remote hosh which works; we need network addresses, routing if applicable, L2 structure (bridges on the host, switches outside, VLANs if any in use).

Comment: Guess this is a very common issue. Smb. who does it all day (sysadmin), should get it done in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Don't you also need `-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT` in combination with `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`?

Comment: Thought there is :INPUT DROP [31177:1522159], that's why there needs to be -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT; but output is on accept not drop? :OUTPUT ACCEPT [1056186:391997142]